# RegEx Pattern Help (php)

Tags: php, regex

After hours of trying to wrap my head around pattern matching, I'm throwing the towel in and turning to the experts...

I have a log file that I'm trying to extract a string from.

The format is like:

```
12:00 SomeText:
1:20 MoreText:
```

The "SomeText/MoreText" is what I need to get. I've come up with the code below but not getting anything near the results I'm expecting:

```
$string = "12:00 SomeText: blah, blah, blah not important";
$regex = '/[0-9]:[0-9] (.*?)\: /';
$entity = preg_split($regex, $string);
```

The regex logic as I understand it is, any number, followed by a colon, followed by any number, followed by white space, the text, followed be a colon, followed by white space

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Can you please expand the format you're receiving? What are the delimiters? Spaces, tabs...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching a single digit, a colon, then a single digit.

```
$string = "12:00 SomeText: blah, blah, blah not important";
$regex = '/[0-9]+:[0-9]+ ([^:]+)/';
$entity = array();
preg_match($regex, $string, $entity);
```

This will match one or more digits, a colon, one or more digits, the rest. `preg_match` will put the entire matching expression (12:00 Some Text) in position 0, and the matched subexpressions (Some Text) after that, so your "Some Text" will be in `$entity[1]`

[Edit]
After the discussion in the comments, I've improved the matching against the header. Before, you had

```
(.*?)\:
```

which will find any character, up to the end of the string, optionally, and then backtrack until it finds the colon. I've replaced it with

```
([^:]+)
```

which will find one or more characters that are not colons, and match them. This saves the regex from looking at "blah, blah, blah..." and then ignoring what it just found.

Comment: beat me to it. although i don't see why the second colon is escaped, either.

Comment: I thought he had that because he wanted only the header, the part between the time and the colon acting as header separator. @Chris Sprague, if you can clarify that, I can make the regex a bit more efficient.

Comment: Indeed, i'm trying to grab just the "SomeText" part of the string.

Comment: Hmmm... playing around with David's solution, the regex seems right as preg_match returns TRUE on matches. Maybe I'm misunderstanding preg_split but shouldn't it return an array of the matches? When I echo $entity it's returning the full string...

Comment: Then you want preg_matches, which takes an array to put your results as a third parameter. I've edited the code.

Comment: Doh.. scratch that last comment. :) Thanks for your help, I got it working!